# Is it possible to specify a directory on the server when proxying with node-http-proxy?

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

Im using http-proxy to proxy any php requests through to apache but I can't figure out how to proxy to a directory on the server...eg if its a php file im saying:
localhost:8090/bar.php -> localhost:80/bar.php
But I would like to proxy to localhost:80/foo/bar.php
I would like to stay away from any URL rewriting though.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've tested my solution below and it seems to be working ok, but I'm not 100% sure if it's the best way to achieve this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.url = '/foo' + req.url;
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '80'
  });
}).listen(8090);
```